# Data Shrink in QuickBooks web connector with ASP.net

Tags: quickbooks, connector

I am using QuickBooks web connector and want to show company data(which is in QuickBooks ) in the web application for that I created a service which is communicating with web connector and getting all the data.
And for doing it I think I have to create a local DB where I can store all the data. Is it correct approach ?

```
If yes then How can I shrink QuickBooks data with my local DB
If No then what need to in this case
```

I am new in QuickBooks Please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why, specifically, do you need to "shrink" your data? QuickBooks data files are teeny tiny (usually well less than 1gb) compared to what any modern database system can handle. Additionally, even if you are worried about how much data you store, you can just be selective about what you pull from QuickBooks - you don't *have* to store everything you get back from QuickBooks, just store what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the web connector, you can't control when your service will be called. So there is a need to store the data somewhere; otherwise you may not have any data to display when your user logs in. Your idea to use a database as a repository for data is an approach that has wide acceptance in the domain of interactive web sites and beyond.

If the source of your data is one or more QuickBooks company files, it is extremely unlikely that you will have a need to shrink your data. The maximum size of a company file is orders of magnitude below the storage capacity of modern database systems, and 1TB hard disks currently retail for around $100US.

For the sake of overall efficiency and maintainability, it is a good idea to query for and store only the data your application needs. Learn how to use the IncludeRetElement qbXML element in your requests to filter the data that is returned from QuickBooks.